# Prey preference - can I use a paired t- or wilcoxon test?

Tags: independence, wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-data

I have done an experiment in which I looked at the prey preference of an aquatic invertebrate. I used 10 containers all with one predator but with different densities of prey. I used two different prey species of which the densities were similar for every container. For example container 1 contained 5 individuals of prey A and 5 of prey B. Container 2 contained 10 individuals of prey A and 10 of prey B and so on.
Now I want to see which prey is prefered by the predator. My data looks as followed:

> prey.a <- c(5,5,10,10,9,12,13,8,15,17) ## number of captured prey (A)
>
> prey.b <- c(5,5,4,2,8,8,4,9,4,6) ## number of captured prey (B)
>
> prey.density <- c(10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,40,40) ## total number of prey available (A and B)

My initial thought was to use a paired t-test. The data violate the assumption of independent samples because they are kind of paired that is why I thought a paired t-test. However, my data violate the assumption of normality so perhaps a Wilcoxon test for paired measurements would be suitable.

The thing is that both these test are designed for a before and after treatment which I don't have. Thus, I'm not really sure if I can actually use these tests. The problem is tha it's a paired rank test of the differences and my low density treatments will always be ranked lower than my high density treatments.

My question is; What would be a suitable test to analyse these data?

I also had this wild thought about a GLMM in which I use the container as a random effect and add prey species as a fixed effect, nevertheless, normality.

btw I used different prey densities because I also looked at the effect of prey density on the total number of captured prey, which has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: You're right that they're not independent. One approach would be to condition on the total prey taken at each point (since you're interested in *preference*, not how hungry they were) and look at it as a binomial response; you'd presumably do a logistic regression. That is, your model would be for the *proportion* of those taken that were species A. You mention GLMM, so why wouldn't you do something like a binomial logit model?

Answer (score 4):

Why not some form of regression?

Prey captured ~ prey type + prey density ?

Since the outcome is a count, it might be best to use Poisson or negative binomial regression.

Comment: That was actually what I meant with the GLMM. model <- glmer(capture.rate ~ species + (1|container), family="poisson")). That would at least account for the dependent samples. I forgot about the fact that I can use different distributions so the whole normality assumption won't matter. Thanks

Comment: I am usually a fan of GLMM but I am not sure it is needed here - unless there is some reason to think that the containers are different in some way that violates independence.

Comment: When treating the data in a regression form there will be two samples that come from the exact same container thus the exact same predator. A single predator might be larger, hungrier, older and so on. That would violate the  independence assumption, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense (and a good example of why substantive knowledge is key).

Answer (score 0):

How about the Mann Whitney U test for matched pairs? http://www.le.ac.uk/bl/gat/virtualfc/Stats/nonpcom.html